# Javascript - using a closure and getters, while preserving object identity

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I wrote a javascript library which stores and controls the state of a board game.

I want the safety of not allowing a consumer of the library to modify the game state, so I use a closure to define the functions they *should* use to modify the state in a well-constrained way. And I also use `_.cloneDeep` on the internal variables and expose this cloned version.

```
const game = () => {

  const gameState = {};

  const setSomeState = val => {
    gameState.field = val;
  };

  return {
    gameState: () => _.cloneDeep(gameState),
    setSomeState: setSomeState,
  };

}

module.exports = game;
```

The problem is that if the game state changes, they have to explicitly ask for an update by re-calling `game.gameState()`, rather than if instead of using `_.cloneDeep` I returned the actual reference to the internal variable then any changes to the object's fields would be readily available.

Is it possible to get the best of both worlds, where a consumer can get an object that 1) automatically has its contents up to date with the game state, but 2) they can't modify?

EDIT:
I should add that the reason I care about preserving identity and avoiding the consumer having to re-clone the internal state, is that I have a React app that uses this library, and re-cloning the game state variables causes them to technically be different objects, so React thinks certain components need to re-render, even if the objects did not change their contents, just their identity.

Comment: I would like to know more about why will it be a problem if user is trying to change something?

Comment: For example, they might assign some game state object to a variable of their own, and pass that variable around, forget that that variable references the same object being used as the actual game state (easy to forget since now this object could be referenced in some completely different part of the code base), and alter the game in unintended ways.

Comment: Is this game frontend only or it has some form of backend? Will this game be played on the network? If it has some backend why can't we do some validation in the backend?

Even if you are able to achieve this your endpoints are accessible, a little clever person and create a similar data structure and use tools like postman to send request to the backend.

Comment: Frontend only for the most part. Sends some messages to a lil socket server, but only so different clients can communicate. The server's handlers basically just pass the messages along, and the server holds almost no information. (Ideally I'll cut out the server entirely and use a peer-to-peer thing at some point.)

Comment: If you care about object identities, just make your objects immutable and return them directly instead of copies